# JavaScript: Making an Embedded video resume position after page change

Tags: javascript, video, embed, html, embedded-video

So, I am currently working on building an experiential webpage as a personal project. I have a sidebar that is consistent among all pages, and I would like it to have one embedded youtube playlist that will play on page start, and then PICK UP FROM WHERE IT LEFT OFF WHEN THE PAGE IS CHANGED (this is the important part).

Is there a function that I can call that would use, say, the position in song from the previous page? Ideally, anyone viewing the page would go in order from page a ->b -> c -> d.  I only need the video to pick up in that order, though if it is possible for it to continue regardless of what page is changed to, that would be cool.

Comment: What have you tried? Edit your Q and post your code. As you're new to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so other users can better help youl.

Comment: as a starting point you could use a cookie to store the position (currentTime) of the video and pick that up on page load and use it to reposition the playhead, but to repeat @xlm's suggestion ... give it a try, show us what you have and then we can help